# Directus Nodejs app not working with apache

Tags: node.js, apache, directus

I am trying to run my Directus App which is a Nodejs app on my Apache server on Ubuntu 20.
I followed some most common tutorials and started pm2 with my app name imt which is running on port 8056. I am getting 500 internal server error.

Here is my apache conf code :

```
ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location /api>
      ProxyPass https://localhost:8056
      ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8056
   </Location>
```

Is this correct configuration ? 8056 is the port of my Directus App. What is wrong here ?

```
/home/myusername/scripts/imt_project
```

is the location of my app.

I have also set  `DocumentRoot /home/myusername/scripts/imt_project`